# Angular Material cdk-container and main site fixed header z-index override

Tags: css, angular, angular-material-5

I have site with `fixed header` in angular material with `z-index` of `1100`.

While i have some `mat-menu` in my site which overlap the header with `z-index:1200` and had class `cdk-overlay-container` (angular material class) which is default behavior.

To override this i just decrease the `cdk-overlay-container` `z-index` to `1000` so that it go behind the `fixed header` and all things ok to me.

**Problem**

But when i open my material dialog which uses same `cdk-overlay-container` and same `z-index` it shows my fixed header above that overlay because of its high `z-index`, So any idea how to achieve the above scenario by adding different `class` to `cdk-overlay-container` so that my `mat-menu` goes behind the `fixed header` but my `mat-dialog` above all content.

**Screen shoots**

Normal scenario
https://www.screencast.com/t/XhB2szH3gZe

Problem scenario
https://www.screencast.com/t/fYrMYFEOd

I have one solution by type-script(that when dialog show lower the z-index of header) but i need some pure CSS solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out my self

Just override the `z-index` of `cdk-overlay-container`

In your `style.scss`

```
.cdk-overlay-container{
  z-index:999; //lower then fixed header z-index so it goes behind it
}
```

and in your component `dialog.scss`

```
.cdk-overlay-container{
   z-index:2000 !important; //higher then fixed header z-index so it comes above
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: using important is not good practice, see discussion here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css#:~:text=important%20is%20a%20bad%20CSS,to%20the%20latest%20important%20value.

Comment: @ModusPwnens then why css is giving us that rule though ?

Comment: it seems as though it should only be used if absolutely necessary. I'm working on a better work around at the moment and will post an answer when I find one.

Comment: ok i am waiting but any how idk why you give that ans negative...

Comment: I minused your answer to your question because it didn't solve the issue and it's not good practice. I gave igsm a plus one because his answer solves the issue and his answer should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 5):

I had similar issue with the full-screen CDK overlay container and the material dialog that should come above anything. The issue is, that if you use provided material elements like Dialog, Tooltip, Menu, they all work with overlay CDK. Then, on top, you may have your custom Overlay service that utilizes CDK. In my case, two cdk-container-overlay divs were created. z-index is 1000 by default and the latest instance overlap's when both overlays are required at the same time.

Some will yell that it is not Angular way, but in my case, I ended up adding a backdropClass to the config of the material dialog. Then, I simply select dialog backdrop's parentNode and manually add z-index on demand.

```
public openFeedbackDialog(): void {
    this.dialog.open(FeedbackFormComponent, {
        width: '450px',
        maxHeight: '450px',
        minHeight: '200px',
        backdropClass: 'feedbackBackdrop',
        hasBackdrop: true
    })
    window.document.querySelector<any>('.feedbackBackdrop').parentNode.style.zIndex = "1001"
}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah good approach, ill try that in future and will let you know if need any help currently ill added above fix in my project and its working fine :) ... Anyhow Thanks for this effort. Cheers!

Comment: Works fine, thx. Alternatively you could query the document for class .cdk-overlay-container. then you don't need a custom backdrop class: window.document.querySelector<any>('.cdk-overlay-container').style.zIndex = "1001"

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the issue by using custom `OverlayContainer` class. You can find example with implementation [here](https://www.bbogdanov.dev/post/angular-material-overlay-hack-overlay-container).